# Instantiate java generic class gives compile time error

Tags: java, generics

Instantiate generic class gives compile time error: "cannot be instantiated directly"

```
    public synchronized <T extends Persistable> T read(Class<T> clazz) {
    T temp;
    try {
        if(cache.containsKey(clazz)){
            return (T)cache.get(clazz);
        }else{
            Properties properties = getProperties();
            temp = internalFileManager.read(clazz,     properties.getProperty(clazz.getSimpleName()));
            if(temp == null){
                temp = new T();///cannot be instantiated directly
            }
            cache.put(clazz,temp);
            return temp;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("","",e);
        return null;
    }
    }
```

This is the problem so nor new T() nor new Class() works, it might just easy solution just need some hint.

Comment: It's `newInstance()` and not `newInstace()`.

Comment: oh yes. It's newInstance().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate a generic parameter like that (as you've discovered).

However, you do have a `Class` instance available, so you could call `clazz.newInstance()` there instead.

(This assumes that the class in question has a public, no-arg constructor.  If that's not the case, you'll need to [use reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) to find the [Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) instance you need, and then invoke it with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: clazz.newInstace() gives an error : "symbol cannot be resolved"

Comment: @Pedro Is that a typo in your comment, or in the code itself?

Comment: sorry my fault.. You was right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate a generic. I see that you have the `Class` object of `T` so you can do

```
if(temp == null){
   temp = clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Sidenote:

If `T` was **unbounded**, then you could have instantiated it with `new Object()`